# Issue with selecting a row in a tableView in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

By looking at the title you can pretty much realise what my problem is,I have a table view on my storyboard and no matter waht i try to do still nothing happens when i select a row
I tried with this code:

```
func tableView (tableView:UITableView , cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell{
    var cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell :UITableViewCell

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    var st = indexPath

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
    var word:NSString
    word=message[indexPath.row] as NSString
    if word.containsString("You just sent a message"){
        cell.textLabel.text = word.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")[1].componentsSeparatedByString(":")[6] as NSString}
    if word.containsString("Users"){
        var smth = word.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        var word = ""
        for i in (1..<smth.count){
            var hey = smth[i] as NSString
            var elst = ""
            elst += hey as NSString
            word += elst + " "

        }
        cell.textLabel.text = word
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = word
    }
        return cell

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}


func tableView(tableView:UITableView ,numberOfRowsInSection section :NSInteger)->Int{
    return message.count
}
```

After goggle-ing this I found the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function to be the one in charge but still nothing happens after implementing it

As you can see the main function d oes something and it really puts someting in each cell [the right thing]

Any ideeas why this is happenning?

Answer (score 4):

Did you set the table view's delegate as this swift class? Where is the tableview  is it in IB or you created it with code? If in code you got to set the delegate manually, if in IB then you can drag drop to set the delegate.

If table view is setup and initialized via code do this,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        var tableView:UITableView = UITableView()

        tableView.delegate = self;

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

**Note: Without specifying UITableViewDelegate as above next to UIViewController I was getting an error but the same would generate a warning with Objective C.**

Comment: This was the issue and I just opened chrome to say exactly the same thing.The code version is interesting and good to know.  Thank you nevertheless.